# filter json data and then use d3.nest

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to understand how I can filter json data, and then create a table with that filtered data.

I started off by looking at this block:
https://gist.github.com/mbostock/844752

That's exactly the kind of table I want.

Then I saw this stackexchange post on filtering: [D3 filtering data points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186220/d3-filtering-data-points)

I used that as a template for the filter function that I added. It works! 
However, now I can't seem to get the nest to work, because the filtered data that is returned has a key for each object.

In console it looks like this:

```
[6: Object, 7: Object, 34: Object, 35: Object, 36: Object]
```

whereas the unfiltered data looks like this:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

If anyone has any ideas how I might access the 'country' keys inside the filtered data, that would be really helpful! I've been searching, and haven't found an answer. Please let me know if I can clarify.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<table id="countries">
</table>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function filterJSON(json, key, value) {
      var result = [];
      for (var indicator in json) {
        if (json[indicator][key] === value) {
          result[indicator] = json[indicator];
        }
      }
      return result;
    }

d3.json("nest.json", function(json) {

filtered = filterJSON(json, 'Aspect', 'Economy');
console.log(filtered);
console.log(json);

var datanest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.Country; })
        .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
        .map(json); // this is the nest that works, using the full json file.

var nestfilt = d3.nest()        
        .key(function(d) { return d.Country; })
        .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
        .map(filtered); // this is the nest that does not work. 

var tr = d3.select("#countries")
  .selectAll("tr")
  .data(d3.entries(datanest))
 .enter().append("tr");

tr.append("th")
  .text(function(d) { return d.key; });

tr.selectAll("td")
  .data(function(d) { return d.value; })
  .enter().append("td")
  .text(function(d) { return d.Aspect + ":  " + d.Value + ", " + d.Year; });

});

</script>
```

Comment: It would be better if you post your data as well

Comment: Good to know. My data is the same as this sample: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/844752#file-sample-json except I added years. Next time I ask a question I'll be sure to add the data. Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change filterJSON to do `result.push(json[indicator])` instead of `result[indicator] = json[indicator]`? That way, result is an array and has the same format as the unfiltered data.

Here is an example of this in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5o8xkcz). It seems to be working, except the Year is undefined because I think my sample data is different than yours.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is precisely what I needed.