# D3 Filter Data Based on slider value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am importing a tsv file that I want to filter based on the values of three sliders.

Currently, I can import the data and filter but I'm not sure exactly how to go about modifying the filter whenever the sliders are updated.

I want the filter to be re-cast whenever the slider moves so that only the particular row of data that meets the filters is returned.

**Here is the part that responds to slider movement**:

```
d3.select("#Estimators").on("input", function() {
  update_ests(+this.value);});

// update the elements
function update_ests(Estimators) {
  // adjust the text on the range slider
  d3.select("#Estimators-value").text(Estimators);
  d3.select("#Estimators").property("value", Estimators);
 }
```

**Here is the part that imports the data:**

```
d3.tsv("{{url_for('static',filename='Countour_Data.txt')}}",function(data) {

var Contour_Data = data.map(function(d,i) {
    return {
        Max_Depth: +d.Max_Depth,
        Learn_Rate: +d.Learn_Rate,
        Estimators: +d.Estimators,
        Contour: JSON.parse(d.Contour)
    }})
.filter(function(d) { return d.Max_Depth == 3 &&  d.Learn_Rate == 0.05 && d.Estimators == 100})
.map(function(d){return d.Contour;})

var ScaleX = d3.scale.linear().range([0,500]).domain(d3.extent(Contour_Data[0], function(d){return d.x; }))
var ScaleY = d3.scale.linear().range([0,300]).domain(d3.extent(Contour_Data[0], function(d){return d.y; }))
var ScaleColor = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0,1])
            .range(["white","blue"]);


d3.select("#Contour")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(Contour_Data[0])
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class","pixels")
    .attr("x",function(d){return ScaleX(d.x)})
    .attr("y",function(d){return ScaleY(d.y)})
    .attr("width",15)
    .attr("height",15)
    .attr("fill",function(d){return ScaleColor(d.pred)})
})
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186220/d3-filtering-data-points) may help.

Comment: Worked, thanks!  Needed to get away from the .filter() function.